# storing Instances of student into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, constructor

Im trying to store these instances of student inside of this array.

Student:

```
public Student(string Value)
    {
        FirstName = Value;
        LastName = Value;
        StudentID = Value;
    }
```

Here is the Array

```
string[] student = new string[4];
    { ElementarySchoolStudent, MiddleSchoolStudent, HighSchoolStudent, CollegeStudent }
```

Each constructor is like this and they use the Student method.

```
CollegeStudent(string value) : base(value) { }
```

How exactly would I go about storing these instances in the array? When I do it like that i get the error message:

> college student is a type which is not valid in the given context.

What's the correct way to code it exactly?

Comment: Note you really need to work on your question asking skills. This and your last question leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: What is `CollegeStudent` (and other students)? Is it a class that's derived from `Student`? Are you wanting to store the type itself or an object of that type? If you're wanting to store the object, what are the names of those variables? Why is this a string array?

Answer (score 0):

From this and the last question, maybe you want something like this

**Given**

```
public class Student
{
   public string FirstName  { get; set; }
   public string LastName   { get; set; }
   public string StudentID  { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var students = new Student[]
{
   new Student(){FirstName = "bob",LastName = "blerg",StudentID = "23432"},
   new Student(){FirstName = "dan",LastName = "flib",StudentID = "4564"},
   new Student(){FirstName = "jib",LastName = "jab",StudentID = "564"},
};

foreach (var student in students)
   Console.WriteLine($"{student.StudentID} : {student.FirstName}, {student.LastName}");
```

**Output**

```
23432 : bob, blerg
4564 : dan, flib
564 : jib, jab
```

<sub>***Note** : Add constructor or pepper and salt to taste*</sub>